# Can I just copy and rename a VirtualBox vm?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to create a new vm starting from an existing virtualbox vm.

Can I just copy and paste and rename the existing one?

Comment: could someone edit this question to fix the 'virutalbox' mistyping? it doesn't help when searching for virtualbox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Virtualbox will not allow you to register two VDI files with the same UUID.

> Cannot register the hard disk
>   '/home/lee/fedora-10-x86-1.vdi' with
>   UUID
>   {06f39a14-97e6-478c-93b9-0ade6dba48d8}
>   because a hard disk
>   '/home/lee/fedora-10-x86-1.vdi' with
>   UUID
>   {06f39a14-97e6-478c-93b9-0ade6dba48d8}
>   already exists in the media registry
>   ('/home/lee/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml').

You will need to clone the VDI file, this copies the original VDI file and assigns a new UUID.

From the gui:

> Shutdown the VM and hit 'Ctrl+Shift+C' or click the 'clone' button. (It looks like a sheep.)

Windows:

```
VBoxManage.exe clonevdi "<Full_path_to_org_vdi>" "<Full_path_to_new_vdi>"
```

Linux:

```
VBoxManage clonevdi <Full_path_to_org_vdi> <Full_path_to_new_vdi>
```

I found a tutorial [here](http://srackham.wordpress.com/cloning-and-copying-virtualbox-virtual-machines/) describing the process.

Comment: Indeed. I recently got caught by that :(

Comment: Alternatively you can copy the *vdi* hard disk with windows/linux and then change UUID with command:  `vboxmanage internalcommands sethduuid <FULL_PATH_TO_VDI>`.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple script to clone a VirtualBox machine. It can create a clone from any snapshot. See my [blog post](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-clone-virtualbox-virtual-machine.html) where you can download the script.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox 4.1 added clone functionality via GUI yesterday.