# Is there a way to clone a vitualbox VM and keep the snapshots?

Tags: virtualbox

As per questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/26092/can-i-just-copy-and-rename-a-virtualbox-vm), cloning a VM in VirtualBox is possible, if not all that streightforward.  However, everything I've seen indicates that before a VM is cloned, all the snapshots need to be folded back into a single disk image.

But, what if I don't want to?  Suppose I want to keep my stack of snapshots on the original, and then clone that VM such that the clone also had the same stack of snapshots available?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copy the whole directory and reimport it as a new virtual machine?

It should be a 1:1 copy with full snapshot history... You may just need manually give the Network card a new MAC though.

Comment: If we're talking about running both the original and the copy on the same machine, I don't think VirtualBox likes having multiple virtual disks with the same UUID.